# How to develop on a Parrot device, like Parrot Asteroid Mini?

Tags: android

I'm looking for solutions to develop on a [Parrot](http://www.parrot.com/usa/products/all-products) device. I'm interested in the existence of any SDK or Developer Tool. I can install simply my Android App to the Device? Should i modify the source code to run it on a Parrot device? Exist any Emulator to test my app behavior in Parrot's environment?

Any solutions interests me!

Comment: Have you had a look at https://devzone.parrot.com/ ?

Comment: Yes i had, but i think those articles are old. [for example](https://devzone.parrot.com/wiki/asteroid-devzone/Set_up_the_development_environment_ST) in this article, teach me how to use Asteroid Tablet skin, but in the newer Eclipse versions i can't use any skins

Answer (score 1):

hi i don't know if this is the proper answer to your question but have a look at this

http://www.intomobile.com/2011/09/07/parrots-ardrone-controller-app-comes-android-sdk-out-too/

and also this

https://projects.ardrone.org/

Comment: I'm more interested in Tablet version.